# Table with longer text in cells

Tags: tables, positioning, tabularx

I have following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newcommand*{\QEDB}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}%
\usepackage{pgf}
%, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\colorlet{Lila}{Orchid!70!}




\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
& $f\leq \mathcal{O}(g)$ & $f\geq \Omega    (g)$ & $f=\Theta(g)$ \\
\hline
Reflexiv & $f(n) \leq c \cdot f(n)\to$      \checkmark für $c=1$ & $f    (n) \geq c \cdot   f(n)\to$  \checkmark für $c=1$ & folgt aus      $\leftarrow$ \\ 
Symmetrisch & $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$      und $g(n) \leq c \cdot f (n)$ für $n>1$         Gegenbsp: $n \leq 1 \cdot n^2$ aber $n^2    \nleq c \cdot n$, denn $\frac{n}{n^2}$      geht gegen unedlich wenn n nach unedlich    geht $\to$ es existiert keine Konstante     $c>0$, die die Bedingung erfüllen kann,     denn es gibt keine obere Schranke. & nein   & ja \\ 
Transitiv & ja & ja & ja \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}\\\\
   \end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have that long text in the same cell... so that the table fits the page.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allow line-breaking in the second column. I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and a centered version of the `X` column type for the second column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} % or 'ngerman' ?
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
%\usepackage{amsthm} 
%\newcommand*{\QEDB}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}%
%\usepackage{pgf}
%%, tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\colorlet{Lila}{Orchid!70!}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|C|c|c|} 
\hline
& $f\leq \mathcal{O}(g)$ 
& $f\geq \Omega(g)$ 
& $f=\Theta(g)$ \\
\hline
Reflexiv 
& $f(n) \leq c \cdot f(n)\to$ \checkmark\ für $c=1$ 
& $f(n) \geq c \cdot f(n)\to$ \checkmark\ für $c=1$ 
& folgt aus $\leftarrow$ \\ 
Symmetrisch 
& $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ und $g(n) \leq c \cdot f(n)$ 
  für $n>1$. Gegenbsp: $n \leq 1 \cdot n^2$ aber 
  $n^2 \nleq c \cdot n$, denn $\frac{n}{n^2}$ geht 
  gegen unendlich wenn $n$ nach unendlich geht 
  $\to$ es existiert keine Konstante $c>0$, die die 
  Bedingung erfüllen kann, denn es gibt keine obere 
  Schranke. 
& nein   
& ja \\ 
Transitiv & ja & ja & ja \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Cherry - You're welcome. By the way, you may want to check the correctness of the claim that `\frac{n}{n^2}\to\infty` if `n\to\infty`.